# Time of death in-hospital?

Tags: mimic-iii

How do you determine the exact time of death for in-hospital deaths?  I see DOD (day of death) but not a time stamp.

Answer (score 4):

On MIMIC-III v1.1 and v1.3:

```
SELECT DEATHTIME FROM mimiciii.admissions 
WHERE DEATHTIME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DEATHTIME ASC LIMIT 500 ;
```

[image]

Maybe you use MIMIC-II.